# "Cannot access a disposed object.\r\nObject name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'

Tags: c#, sockets

In the `ClientClass`, I have two threads; one for TCP-IP connection to a localhost and another to keep receiving messages from the localhost.

In case the connection gets broken, I close the connection using  `m_DeviceClientSocket.Close()` inside the `catch` block of the method `ConnectToDeviceAndMonitorConnection()`.

**PROBLEM:** Since I close the socket connection, therefore, the whole `m_DeviceClientSocket` object is dereferenced. This leads to another error inside the `catch` block of the method  `GetMessagesFromDevice()` and the error says (as shown in the catch block of the code):

> "Cannot access a disposed object.\r\nObject name:
>   'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'

**QUESTION:** How should I create the `m_DeviceClientSocket` object, which can be closed, reconnected and is available to both the threads?

```
class ClientClass
{
    Thread t1_DeviceConnectionMonitor, t2_receiveDeviceMessages;
    static readonly object m_IsConnectedToDevice_Locker = new object();
    bool m_IsConnectedToDevice = false;

    //Device - Communication Variables
    string m_DeviceURL = "127.0.0.1";
    int m_DevicePort = 23;
    TcpClient m_DeviceClientSocket = new TcpClient();
    NetworkStream m_DeviceServerStream = default(NetworkStream);

    public ClientClass()
    {
        //Thread for CONNECTION Monitoring
        t1_DeviceConnectionMonitor = new Thread(ConnectToDeviceAndMonitorConnection);
        t_DeviceConnectionMonitor.Start();

        //Thread to RECEIVE messages
        t2_receiveDeviceMessages = new Thread(GetMessagesFromDevice);
        t2_receiveDeviceMessages.Start();
    }

    //Connect to Device
    void ConnectToDeviceAndMonitorConnection()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (!m_IsConnectedToDevice)
            {
                try
                {
                    //Connect to device server
                    m_DeviceClientSocket.Connect(m_DeviceURL, m_DevicePort);
                    m_DeviceServerStream = m_DeviceClientSocket.GetStream();
                    SetDeviceConnectionStatus(true);
                }
                catch (SocketException se)
                {
                    if (m_DeviceClientSocket.Connected)
                        m_DeviceClientSocket.Close(); //This Close() statement dereference the complete "m_DeviceClientSocket" object
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //RECEIVE messages from the device
    public void GetMessagesFromDevice()
    {
        string messageReceivedFromDevice;

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                var buffersize = m_DeviceClientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize;
                byte[] instream = new byte[buffersize];

                int status = m_DeviceServerStream.Read(instream, 0, buffersize);
                if (status == 0)
                {
                    SetDeviceConnectionStatus(false);
                }
                messageReceivedFromDevice = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(instream);
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //I ENETER HERE AND THE EXCEPTIONS SAYS: ""Cannot access a disposed object.\r\nObject name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'"
            }
        }
    }

    //Thread Safety is needed to set the device connection status
    public void SetDeviceConnectionStatus(bool status)
    {
        lock (m_IsConnectedToDevice_Locker)
        {
            m_IsConnectedToDevice = status;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to recreate the socket.

Comment: Although in general it's a programming error to catch `ObjectDisposedException`, it's fairly standard practice for socket operations, as they can't be interrupted other than by closing the socket. A socket is always rendered unusable by I/O errors and you have to restart from scratch afterwards.

Comment: @DanielA.White: Yes, I know that I have to recreate the socket but the question is, how should I recreate it? Initially, I create the socket object in its declaration as a member variable. But after closing it, should I recreate it inside the same thread which closed it?

Comment: _"How should I create the m_DeviceClientSocket object"_ -- what have you tried? This sort of thing needs to be handled in your application protocol level. I.e. once a connection's been broken, there is no way to recover for that connection. The endpoints need to start all over, which means the server (listening) endpoint discards its client-specific socket (the listening socket remains of course, and depending on how you implement the recovery, you could even retain any client-specific state objects that are not the socket itself), and the client needs to reconnect with a brand new socket.

Comment: But without a good [mcve] showing the scenario you're dealing with and showing what exactly you've tried already, and without a clear explanation of what specific difficulty you're having with that attempt to solve the problem, your question is too broad.